# In American English, is it okay to pronounce the /v/ sound as the /f/ sound at the end of a word?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I've notice that when I speak, it is really hard to pronounce the /v/ at the end of a word when it is followed by another consonant, so I really want to know how native speakers pronounce it.
*For example: have got, have had, have gone, etc.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really good to mispronounce words, it may lead to misunderstanding

For example, **have** would be heard as **half**

> I **have** gone

is very different to

> I **half** gone

which a native speaker might interpret to be

> I'm half gone

meaning you are **half-way drunk** instead of you **went somewhere**.

Native speakers tend to have a distinct "v" sound when it is called for

Comment: so how can I pronounce that distinct /v/ sound in that situation?

Comment: @NopeeEponn Do you have problems pronouncing /v/ in general or only at the end of a word?

Comment: I have problems only at the end of a word.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you tried talking **more slowly and pronouncing each syllable** it would help. It will take some time to retrain your mouth to make the sound. Constant daily practice, then suddenly it will work. It took me about 3 months to get used to rolling my R's in German so I wouldn't have to think about it.

Comment: The only place where it's acceptable to pronounce the V as an "F" is "have to", as in "I have to go to the bathroom.".

Answer (score 0):

In each case you have the **V** preceded by a vowel. A vowel is voiced and so it seems to me it would be easier to produce the voiced *v* instead of the unvoiced *f*, especially when it is followed by a voiced consonant such as the *g* in *got*; and [this is what English speakers do](http://forvo.com/search/have/en/).

Answer (score 0):

In the specific phrase "have to [do something]" in the sense of "be obligated," many American speakers do indeed devoice the /v/, presumably in anticipation of the t. Similarly in the third person "has to" the /z/ of "has" is often devoiced. Otherwise, as the other answers say, devoicing does not occur in any register, as far as I know.